# Using Depth First Search, how can I retrieve a list of lists of coordinates to determine islands?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, depth-first-search

I am attempting to use DFS on a 2D array/tilemap to determine islands generated after my drunkard's walk algorithm. The walk carves out a pre-allocated 2d array (deletes tiles) and I want to determine the islands (or platforms in my scenario, for a 2d sidescroller), so I can place hills appropriately along these platforms/islands.

The problem is that I keep running into a stack overflow when I attempt DFS on the outer perimeter, the std vector I pass around reaches about 3000~ (ptr) elements. I have no issues capturing the inner islands which stay at roughly 20 - 50 elements.

I use a pseudo map of 0, 1, and 2 to determine what has happened.
1 is tile here, not checked
0 is null
2 is tile found, added to island list

```
    if (pseudoMap[y][x] == 1)
    {
    Uint8 platform = 1;

    PlatformDFS(&pseudoMap, x, y, &platform, visitedPlatform);

    if (platform == 1) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(graphicsRef->GetRenderer(), 0, 0, 255, 255);

        platformsFound.push_back(visitedPlatform);

        for (Vector2 gridPos : visitedPlatform) {
            tileMap[(int)gridPos.y][(int)gridPos.x]->SetTileLayer(TileLayer::Platform);
            SDL_Rect r((int)gridPos.x * 5, int(gridPos.y) * 5, 5, 5);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(graphicsRef->GetRenderer(), &r);
            SDL_RenderPresent(graphicsRef->GetRenderer());
        }

        PrintTileMapToConsole(1);
        std::cout << "Platform found starting at " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << " NO platform found at " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
        visitedPlatform.clear();
    }
    }
```

I pass the pseudo map to the dfs fcn for marking
current x,y to check
a flag that will be marked 0 if we go out of bounds, meaning we are checking the cave itself
and the list of tiles belonging to the current island/platform

```
    void TileManager::PlatformDFS(std::vector<std::vector<Uint8>>* pmap, int x, int y, Uint8* platformFlag, std::vector<Vector2>& platformTiles)
    {
    if (IsNotInBounds(x, y)) {
        platformFlag = 0;
        return;
    }
    
    if ((*pmap)[y][x] != 1)
        return;

    Vector2 pos = Vector2(x, y);

    platformTiles.push_back(pos); <--- This is my issue, when we check on the cave perimeter

    (*pmap)[y][x] = 2;
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x, y + 1, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x, y - 1, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x + 1, y, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x - 1, y, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x + 1, y + 1, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x - 1, y - 1, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x + 1, y - 1, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    PlatformDFS(pmap, x - 1, y + 1, platformFlag, platformTiles);
    }


    bool TileManager::IsNotInBounds(int x, int y)
    {
        return y < 0 || y >= tileMap.size() || x < 0 || x >= tileMap[y].size();
    }
```

[image: the blue boxes are the marked platforms showing that it works to a point.]

In the attached image, the blue boxes are the marked platforms showing that it works to a point.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake of forgetting to de-reference the ptr to the flag I was passing to the fcn. Setting the ptr address to 0, instead of setting the value. So the assignment that told my DFS to stop searching wasn't correct.

```
platformFlag = 0;
```

vs.

```
*platformFlag = 0;
```

and I added a check to the first escape condition in DFS, to handle if the current location is set to 0.

Comment: Strongly consider making this sort of mistake impossible by passing references, eg `Uint8& platformFlag`, instead of pointers where possible.